# Import XML from an URL into Excel as a table

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I want to use VBA to automate an process of polling XML data from an external URL to my Excel Workbook. [This](https://www.MASKED.com/export-data/xml/?merchantid=MASKED&hash=MASKED&type=clearing&fromdate=2015-10-22&todate=2015-10-23) is the format of the URL (I have masked sensitive information).

First, I want an VBA script to ask for the daterange (from-to), and put this into the URL.

I get the following back using the browser to open the XML:

```
<Report Type="Clearing" Generated="2015-10-22 16:59:58" MerchantID="MASKED" MerchantName="MASKED" FromDate="2015-10-21" ToDate="2015-10-23">
<Batches>
  <Batch ID="MASKED">
    <Host>EDB</Host>
        <Name>MASKED</Name>
        <ClearingDateTime>2015-10-22 04:15:00</ClearingDateTime>
          <Transactions>
            <Transaction ID="MASKED">
              <ClearingResponseCode>00</ClearingResponseCode>
              <TerminalID>MASKED</TerminalID>
              <TerminalModel>Ingenico IWL250 GPRS</TerminalModel>
              <TransactionType>Sale</TransactionType>
              <SettleTransactionID>MASKED</SettleTransactionID>
              <Online>1</Online>
              <TransactionDateTime>2015-10-21 11:01:23</TransactionDateTime>
              <Amount>24000</Amount>
              <ReceiptNo>000465</ReceiptNo>
              <TerminalRRN>MASKED</TerminalRRN>
              <CardGroup>MasterCard</CardGroup>
              <ApprovalCode>MASKED</ApprovalCode>
              <CardIssuer>Foreign MasterCard/Eurocard</CardIssuer>
              <CardProduct>Foreign MC/EC</CardProduct
              ><CurrencyCode>NOK</CurrencyCode>
              <TerminalAppVersion>MASKED</TerminalAppVersion>
              <TerminalDateTime>2015-10-21 11:00:54</TerminalDateTime>
              <ExtraData/>
            </Transaction>
            <Transaction ID="MASKED">
              <ClearingResponseCode>00</ClearingResponseCode>
              <TerminalID>MASKED</TerminalID>
              <TerminalModel>Ingenico IWL250 GPRS</TerminalModel>
              <TransactionType>Sale</TransactionType>
              <SettleTransactionID>3MASKED</SettleTransactionID>
              <Online>1</Online>
              <TransactionDateTime>2015-10-21 11:11:11</TransactionDateTime>
              <Amount>6000</Amount>
              <ReceiptNo>000466</ReceiptNo>
              <TerminalRRN>MASKED</TerminalRRN>
              <CardGroup>Visa</CardGroup>
              <ApprovalCode>MASKED</ApprovalCode>
              <CardIssuer>Foreign Visa</CardIssuer>
              <CardProduct>Foreign Visa</CardProduct>
              <CurrencyCode>NOK</CurrencyCode>
              <TerminalAppVersion>MASKED</TerminalAppVersion>
              <TerminalDateTime>2015-10-21 11:10:53</TerminalDateTime>
            <ExtraData/>
            </Transaction>
          </Transactions>
        </Batch>
     <Batch ID="MASKED">
       <Host>NETS Norway</Host>
         <Name>MASKED</Name>
         <ClearingDateTime>2015-10-21 04:19:05</ClearingDateTime>
           <Transactions>
              <Transaction ID="MASKED">
              <ClearingResponseCode>00</ClearingResponseCode>
              <TerminalID>MASKED</TerminalID>
              <TerminalModel>Ingenico IWL250 GPRS</TerminalModel>
              <TransactionType>Sale</TransactionType>
              <SettleTransactionID>MASKED</SettleTransactionID>
              <Online>1</Online>
              <TransactionDateTime>2015-10-20 13:07:21</TransactionDateTime>
              <Amount>100</Amount>
              <ReceiptNo>000028</ReceiptNo>
              <TerminalRRN>MASKED</TerminalRRN>
              <CardGroup>BankAxept</CardGroup>
              <ApprovalCode>MASKED</ApprovalCode>
              <CardIssuer>BBS</CardIssuer>
              <CardProduct>BAX Smartkort</CardProduct>
              <CurrencyCode>NOK</CurrencyCode>
              <TerminalAppVersion>MASKED</TerminalAppVersion>
              <TerminalDateTime>2015-10-20 13:07:09</TerminalDateTime>
              <ExtraData/>
            </Transaction>
          </Transactions>
        </Batch>
</Batches>
```

With this a want to create a table with a filter on top, but only with the fields:

`ClearingDateTime`, `Transaction ID`="MASKED",`ClearingResponseCode`, `TerminalID`, `TerminalModel`, `TransactionType`, `Amount`, `CardGroup`, `CardProduct` and `CurrencyCode`.

Might somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pieced something similar together to get data from Zillow's api where URL request returns some XML. Here are some pieces of that code that should get you going. This cuts out quite a bit, but I think it gets you all the pertinent parts. You can see the format of Zillow's data at this site: http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetDeepComps.htm. Hope this helps!

```
        Sub ZillowDeepCompVf()

        ' Miscrosoft XML v6.0 must be enabled from the VBA editor
        ' To enable, go to Tools>References and check the box next to "Miscrosoft XML v6.0"
    'Set URL
      URL = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepComps.htm?zws-id=" & ZWSID & "&zpid=" & rowZpid & "&count=" & Count & "&rentzestimate=true"

            'Open XML page
            Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
            xmldoc.async = False

            ' Check XML document is loaded
            If xmldoc.Load(URL) Then

                Set xmlMessage = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//message/text")
                Set xmlMessageCode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//message/code")

                ' Check for an error message
                If xmlMessageCode.Text <> 0 Then

                    ' Return error message
                    DC.Range(ErrorMessage & i + headers) = xmlMessage.Text

                Else
                    ' Get XML data from Zillow
                    Set xmlComparables = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//response/properties/comparables")
                    Set xmlCompList = xmlComparables.SelectNodes("comp")
                    Set xmlPrincipal = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//response/properties/principal")

                ' Loop through comparables
                i = 1
                headers = headers + 1
                For i = 1 To xmlCompList.Length

                 'Home Details
                    Set xmlComp = xmlCompList(i - 1)
                    Set xmlHomeDetails = xmlComp.SelectSingleNode("links/homedetails")

                    If xmlHomeDetails Is Nothing Then
                        DC.Range(HomeDetails & i + headers) = "No home details available"
                    Else
                        DC.Range(HomeDetails & i + headers).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & xmlHomeDetails.Text & """,""Zillow Details"")"
                    End If

                 ' Retrieve Street address, ZIP code ,City, zPID
                Set xmlStreetAddress = xmlComp.SelectSingleNode("address/street")
                Set xmlZipCode = xmlComp.SelectSingleNode("address/zipcode")
                Set xmlCity = xmlComp.SelectSingleNode("address/city")
                Set xmlState = xmlComp.SelectSingleNode("address/state")
                Set xmlZPID = xmlComp.SelectSingleNode("zpid")

                ' Push data to spreadsheet
                If xmlStreetAddress Is Nothing Then
                    DC.Range(Address & i + headers) = "N/A"
                Else
                DC.Range(Address & i + headers) = xmlStreetAddress.Text
                End If

                If xmlCity Is Nothing Then
                DC.Range(City & i + headers) = "N/A"
                Else
                DC.Range(City & i + headers) = xmlCity.Text
                End If

                If xmlState Is Nothing Then
                    DC.Range(State & i + headers) = "N/A"
                Else
                DC.Range(State & i + headers) = xmlState.Text
                End If

                If xmlZipCode Is Nothing Then
                    DC.Range(ZipCode & i + headers) = "N/A"
                Else
                DC.Range(ZipCode & i + headers) = xmlZipCode.Text
                End If

                If xmlZPID Is Nothing Then
                    DC.Range(pzpid & i + headers) = "N/A"
                Else
                DC.Range(pzpid & i + headers) = xmlZPID.Text
                End If

                 'Retrieve & push LastSold Date
                Set xmllastSoldDate = xmlComp.SelectSingleNode("lastSoldDate")
                If xmllastSoldDate Is Nothing Then
                    DC.Range(LastSold & i + headers) = "NA"
                Else
                    DC.Range(LastSold & i + headers) = xmllastSoldDate.Text
                End If
...
                Next i 'end of iterate through the comps

                'Sort the data
                Set Data = DC.Range(Cells(headers + 1, 1), Cells(i + headers, LastColumn))
                Data.Sort Key1:=DC.Range("H" & i + headers), order1:=xlDescending
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually sorted it with very little script. Bare in mind I've never programmed in VBA before, so I might have done it a bit 'stupid'.

I created a UserFrom, where I added drowndown lists which I populated to select date from and to. From this I built the date format as a string.

Then I built the query as this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:="https://www.MASKED.com/export-data/xml/?merchantid=MASKED&hash=MASKED&type=clearing&fromdate=" & FraDato & "&todate=" & TilDato, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("Data!A1")
```

It gently populated all data into a huge Excel spreadsheet nicely as a table.

From there I just used VBA to remove the rows not needed :)

Thanx for the assistance though :)